# How to migrate from command line Git to EGit?

Tags: git, egit

I have a project with 4 packages.  I have a Git repo in each package at the source code folder level.  How do I migrate these 4 repos from command line Git to EGit?

Edit: I looked at a couple of EGit tutorials and they seem to be about Git, as prepratory background for EGit usage, or about EGit and new repositories, but nothing about migration for existing repositories.

Edit: Here is a better formulation of the problem:
[Migrating to EGit with an existing Eclipse project and nested Git repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107801/can-egit-be-used-with-existing-eclipse-projects-and-existing-git-repos)

Comment: Please do not abandon and create duplicate questions - if you realize you can ask your question better - just edit the question with what you've learned to make your question clearer/more specific.

Answer (score 1):

### Do nothing

A git repo, is a git repo. It doesn't matter what GUI you use to view/interact with it - the git repository itself doesn't change, there are no migration steps.

### Learn about EGit

Understanding that using or not using EGit has no direct effect on your repository - just [follow the docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories). If you have a specific problem, edit the question indicating what that is.

Comment: I never meant to imply migration converted an existing Git repo to EGit form, thus, I agree there is no direct effect on the repo. I just want to enable GUI access to the repo.

Comment: It's in the docs: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories

Comment: Project creation seems necessary after the point at which Git repos have been selected in the Import wizard. No project is found when I try to import. This might be due to the fact that the Git repo is not in the same folder as my Eclipse project. I have 4 repos per project, so naturally they are nested.

Answer (score 0):

Note that egit depends on jgit.

jgit may not implement all the features found in git or fix all the bugs.