# can EGit be used with existing Eclipse projects and existing Git repos?

Tags: git, egit

I have been using Eclipse and Git.  Now I want to use EGit.  My project has 4 packages.  Each package has a Git repo.

When I import Git repos into EGit, there is an instruction in the user docs to import or create .project files.  These .project files might be Eclipse related.  I already have Eclipse projects so I don't want to create new projects.  Can I still use EGit to have GUI access to Git repos without creating new projects or importing projects?

Project creation and importation follows the point in the wizard where a Git repo is selected.   It seems strange to select a package specific Git repo and then proceed to import a project that is not package specific.  Will I have a problem if my project file is not package specific, but my Git repo is package specific. It would also seem strange to import or create projects 4 times since I have 4 Git repos.  I have been working for many months with Eclipse without EGit using only 1 project.

Edit: When I try to import an existing project, no project is found.  This might be due to the fact the Git repo folder is not on the same level as the Eclipse project.

Comment: Have you tried selecting "Team/Share project..." from the project's context menu?

Comment: This doesn't matter, the context menu (and everything related to version control) is called "Team" anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A bit like "[Importing git project into workspace without using egit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243568/importing-git-project-into-workspace-without-using-egit)", you should have your git repo intialized where the `.project` and `.classpath` are.

That facilitates the "[Import from existing Git Repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories)".

[image: Import]

Comment: I can't move all 4 existing folders, each of them named .git into the same directory unless Git provides some way of customizing the folder name.

Comment: @H2ONaCl 3+ years later, this isn't about moving the folders, but imprting the project into Eclipse workspace. The folders remains where they are.